# Amending REST API function without deactivate/activate plugin every time changes is made

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api, api

I am working on WordPress development where I have to create a custom REST API in a custom plugin. But every time I am amending the the REST API functions, I have to deactivate and activate the plugin to make the changes works on browser. I find it time consuming and a bit annoying.

Is there any way to add/edit/delete a REST API without deactivating/activate the plugin?

My REST API is inside <plugin_name>_plugin.php and the route registration is outside of construct function.

[image]

Comment: Changes to REST API functions should not require deactivating and reactivating the plugin. That’s not normal.  You may have some sort of caching enabled, which could explain the behaviour.

Comment: Hi Jacob, you are correct. thank you. now it is fixed.